# How to detect if multiple players have the same scores?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is my command, it should only activate if all players have avance score on 0:

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={avance=0}]
```

I thought that with `@a` it would only be true if ALL players have that condition, but the command block output says "Test Passed, count 1"
and that screws up the whole circuit as it depends on the command output being "Test Passed" only when all players have the same score on 0 to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, the easiest is to check if no player does not fulfill the condition:

```
/execute unless entity @a[scores={avance=1..}] unless entity @a[scores={avance=..-1}]
```

You can also add `limit=1` to both of these selectors to improve performance. Thanks to vdvman1 for this tip.

Comment: it does not work, it says there is an error at "avance <--[HERE]" , expected "=", as soon as i type "!" the code turns red

Comment: Oh sorry, I was used to Java (and pretty much every other programming language), where it's "`!=`". In Minecraft it's "`=!`" (for whatever reason). I corrected the command.

Comment: i do not know why but it turns red with both "!=" and "=!"

Comment: you told me there are multiple solutions, do you know what else i can try?

Comment: I'll try it in the game now, I wasn't at a computer so far. Another solution would be to tag all matching players and see if someone without the tag is left.

Comment: That's strange, you actually can't check for not matching scores. This is weird, I thought for sure this would be possible. Well then, another solution. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
scoreboard objectives add test dummy "Test"
execute as @a run scoreboard players add $c test 1
execute as @a if score @s avance matches 0 run scoreboard players add $m test 1
```

First, count players.
And then, count players that avance score is 0

```
execute if score $m test = $c test run say Same!
```

Finally, if players count is same as players that avance is 0, say Same!

Comment: The quote marks `"` around objective names are unnecessary.